# Were the arrested US citizens who walked into Iran merely "hikers"?

Tags: iran

I see that there's another news report on CNN regarding [detained U.S. hikers in Iran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009%E2%80%932011_detention_of_American_hikers_by_Iran).  It seems that all too frequently the media reports similar stories every time some random "hiker" is jailed in a country that is unfriendly to the U.S.  These hikers are typically jailed over espionage, spy charges, or illegal entry.

So my question is: are these people really hikers?  Or is that term coined by the media to mean something else?

I guess I'm wondering why on earth any random U.S. citizen would be hiking through a country knowing that they would be arrested on sight.  Heck, I would ascertain that even if these same people were walking down the middle of Main Street Iran that they would be arrested for *something*.

Edited to add: All three people have since been released from prison.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Yes, they are hikers.**

Firstly, [their credentials](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/12/16/world/middleeast/16hikers.html) don't exactly scream "military" or "espionage":

- Shane Bauer is a freelance photojournalist and journalist who has worked for Pacifica News Service, Mother Jones, The Nation and other left-leaning media outlets, using his fluency in speaking Arabic.
- Sarah Shourd worked in education and social justice in Damascus, Syria where she provided educational opportunities to refugees from the war in Iraq and taught English. Shourd was released by Iran on September 14, 2010 on $500,000 bail.
- Joshua Fattal is an environmentalist and educator, and had been from January to May 2009 a teaching fellow for the International Honors Program (IHP)'s "Health and Community" study abroad program.

The three were working and living in the middle east, and decided to take a holiday to Iraqi Kurdistan.

> “We knew a number of people in Damascus who’d traveled to Iraqi Kurdistan and had a really good time,” said Shon Meckfessel, a friend who accompanied the three on the trip. “We just figured it was a really cool place, and nearby. And it was safe.” They planned their route carefully, Mr. Meckfessel said, deciding to cross into Iraq through Turkey because it seemed safer.

It is also highly likely that they were actually [seized in Iraq](http://www.thenation.com/article/36562/us-hikers-were-seized-iraq) by Iranian forces that had crossed the border.

That said, a [leaked US military report about the event](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/world/iraq-war-logs.html#report/D2430687-FCE7-C5BB-ED19F523FE225046) claims that their presence in that region may not have been purely recreational:

> The lack of coordination on the part of these hikers, particularly after being forewarned, indicates **an intent to agitate and create publicity regarding international policies on Iran.** The leadership in Iran benefits as it focuses the Iranian population on a perceived external threat rather than internal dissension. Kurdish leaders remain concerned about international perceptions regarding security as they seek to increase investment in the KRG. Expect KRG leadership to intervene to return the 3 individuals and the Iranian government to accuse them of being spies. Additionally, KRG leadership may impose additional restrictions on private activities near the Iranian border.

(KRG = Kurdish Regional Government)

Comment: Their credentials are exactly the type that Hollywood CIA movies create for their characters so while interesting they do not really mean anything.  Just because we can not actually see a tie to the CIA/NSA/ISI/etc... Does not mean one does not exist.  But as you point out they appear to be troublemakers not agents of the US.  But they could still be both or agents of a different government altogether... Increasing the tension between Iran and the US could be advantageous for someone else including Isreal.

Comment: @Chad: since when Hollywood movies depict reality?

Comment: @nico - What you appear to be is more important than what you are in actuality.  Hollywood has done an excellent job of selling the average spy as someone with a background you would not suspect especially young male students.  So wether or not it depicts reality it is understandable why Iran could believe they were.  Besides you you voleneer to be the only black guy in a group to spend the night in a haunted house? I didnt think so!

Comment: @Chad: that's the idea they give to the general public, sure, but I doubt that military, secret services, and the likes of them base their arrests on what people look like in movies... it's more about political scheming etc

Comment: @nico - Military does not arrest anyone.  Secret service is part of the treasury the only arrests it makes are for financial crimes, they protect the president but the investigating and arresting office would be the FBI.  And the CIA is an intellegence gathering organization... they dont arrest somuch as rendition people.  They only take people they think actually have intellegence or are in the way of their operations.  The US has several protectiosn that Iran lacks.  Things like reasonable cause, due process, and basic human rights.  None of those are required in Iran.

Comment: @Chad: sure, still all these things have nothing to do with Holliwood. That was my only point.

Comment: @nico It does only in that it is the one that creates these perceptions in the world of our military guys all looking like Val Kilmer, act without/against orders, and generally enjoying killing and blowing things up. And our agents as being super commandos that pose as students and scientists. It puts legitmate american students and scientists abroad for holiday at risk. But the responsiblity for the actions is totally the students. They were very much aware of what they were doing.

Comment: I like the last paragraph. It sort of ties everything together for me. Now I can explain to everyone when they ask WHY they were there. It's obvious they had a motive.

Comment: @nico : since attack on twin towers was portrayed in the series "Loan Gunman" very similarly to the method that was used (before the real attack). It might be other way around, people getting the ideas to apply in reality from Movies, there is no constraint that movies are real, maybe reality has a bit of movies in it too.

Comment: I was never convinced this was accidental. I am sure they were hiking at the time but the "we slipped into Iran by accident" while "holidaying in Iraq" story you can make of what you will. I suspect they were doing this to make a political point. We never got a coherent story in their TV interviews either. Great to see them released regardless of motives.